# Embed function explanation

Tags: r, embed

After reading the documentation of `embed()` from the stats package, I still do not understand the output. If someone could explain the example below in an alternative/simpler way (also the order of the columns) I would appreciate it. Thanks!

```
> x <- 1:10
> embed (x, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    1
[2,]    4    3    2
[3,]    5    4    3
[4,]    6    5    4
[5,]    7    6    5
[6,]    8    7    6
[7,]    9    8    7
[8,]   10    9    8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x <- 1:10
dimension <- 3
```

`embed` function is written in R itself, you can view the source code of it by typing `embed` in the console. The main part of the code for this case is the following

```
n <- length(x)
m <- n - dimension + 1L
data <- x[1L:m + rep.int(dimension:1L, rep.int(m, dimension)) - 1L]
dim(data) <- c(m, dimension)
```

so `n` becomes 10, m is `n - dimension + 1L` which is 8 here. The next line is the most important line. We generate the indexes to subset `x` using `rep.int` command.

```
1L:m #is
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

We repeat `m`, `dimension` times which in this case is

```
rep.int(m, dimension)
#[1] 8 8 8

dimension:1L #is
#[1] 3 2 1
```

Now each value of `dimension:1L` is repeated `rep.int(m, dimension)` times which gives

```
rep.int(dimension:1L, rep.int(m, dimension))
#[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

and we subtract 1 from these numbers returning

```
rep.int(dimension:1L, rep.int(m, dimension)) - 1L
#[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Now the above sequence is added to `1L:m` using recycling technique so you get

```
1L:m + rep.int(dimension:1L, rep.int(m, dimension)) - 1L
#[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

The above is the index to subset values from `x`, since in this case, our `x` is `1:10`, it would return the same values.

```
x[1L:m + rep.int(dimension:1L, rep.int(m, dimension)) - 1L]
#[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

Finally, all these numbers are arranged in a matrix form with `m` rows and `dimension` columns.

```
dim(data) <- c(m, dimension)
data
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    2    1
#[2,]    4    3    2
#[3,]    5    4    3
#[4,]    6    5    4
#[5,]    7    6    5
#[6,]    8    7    6
#[7,]    9    8    7
#[8,]   10    9    8
```